# Regular expression app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I need to retrieve whatever string comes after the `/` and retrieve that string in `GetPost` class below. eg: `/test123`, `/blah`, etc  in the below app should go to class `GetPost`.

How can I implement the above requirements in the code below? Is there any module I need to import?

```
class GetPost(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.write("Permalink")

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([ 
    ('/', HomePage),
    ('/new-post', NewPost),
    ('/create-post', CreatePost),
    ('/.+', GetPost)
    ], debug=True);
```

Comment: If you're going to fix the error, remove the stacktrace too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need to [create a capture group](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/running#URL_Mappings) for the expression you want:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([ 
    ...
    ('/(.+)', GetPost)
    ...
```

and include an extra argument to your get handler:

```
class GetPost(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, captured_thing):
        self.response.write(captured_thing)
```

so that requests to `/xyz` will result in `captured_thing` being set to `'xyz'`.

Comment: But how can i retrive the '/permalink' value in the GetPost class. ?